# FASTLANE ipa size double xcode

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane, bitrise, fastlane-gym

Fastlane gym produces ipa double the size of Xcode. Have skipped symbols and bitcode as well but still the size is around double, also tried app thinning for all variants, no luck. Any idea on how to tweak that?

Comment: xcode is likely building for a single platform, such as generic devices only and fastlane might be configured to do simulator and ios builds, we need to know how each is configured. sounds like your fastlane build has more archs configured

Comment: Please have a look to this thread https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/9741 
and this https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/519 on the official fastlane repository  there is already a solution for this issue on the comments

Comment: @scriptable what do you mean?

Comment: @ali have gone through both the tickets and tested the solutions but none works. I barely am able to get 40mb difference if i skip bitcode and symbols. And fastlane bydefault uses modern build system. The total ipa size from xcode is ~220mb but from gym it is around ~420mb

Comment: thats quite a large app!. when you build with xcode when having a simulator selected it builds using the x86_64 architecture, when you select Generic iOS device, it builds with device architectures, mostly in my case arm64. You can do builds that contain multiple architectures which takes up more space. You may need to configure your arch's

Comment: Im currently using xcodbuild and xcrun to generate ipa. Will check if i can tweak the architecture somehow using commandline. Will update soon.